# How to call confirm_form() directly from another submit function

Tags: forms

I would like to call a confirm_form function for selected items in tableselect. If you select some items, and next you specify a action to perform in select and submit it I want to display confirm_form().
I wrote some code, but it doesn't display any confirm box.

```
function products_manage_delete_confirm($form, &$form_state) {
    if (!isset($form_state['values']['products'])) {
        return;
    }
    $form['products'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $form_state['values']['products']);
    $form['#submit'] = array('products_manage_delete_confirm_submit');
    return confirm_form($form, 
            t('Are you sure want to delete these products.'), 
            'admin/products', 
            NULL, 
            t('Delete'));
}

function products_manage_delete_confirm_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    foreach ($form_state['values']['products'] as $product_id) {
        delete_product($product_id);
    }

    drupal_set_message(t('The product has been deleted.'));
    watchdog('product', 'The product has been deleted.');

    $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/products';
}

function products_manage_options_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    if (!isset($form_state['values']['products']) || !count($form_state['values']['products'])) {
        return;
    }

    $operation = $form_state['values']['operation'];
    $form['products'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $form_state['values']['products']);

    switch ($operation) {
        case 'delete':
            return drupal_get_form('products_manage_delete_confirm');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The form API doesn't do anything with the return value from a submit callback, and you can't use it to inject another form. You're looking for a [multi-step form](http://davidsonj.com/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7) which will be a bit more work

Answer (score 0):

[Check this link.](http://codekarate.com/content/drupal-6-confirm-form-example)

You need to create one more menu using hook_menu(). and in that menu call confirm_call function.

you can check node(Default) module of Drupal for the same. you can see how user asked for confirmation before deleting any node.